# Как проанализировать код большого проекта на PHP на наличие неиспользуемых кусков кода и файлов?

Tags: php, рефакторинг

Есть проект на PHP (более 400 файлов). В коде делались изменения, но не всегда убирался код, который больше не нужен.

Часть php-файлов с классами больше нигде не подключаются, и часть функций в нигде не вызывается.

Есть ли какие-то **инструменты автоматического поиска**:

- php-файлов, которые больше нигде не инклюдятся и не используются через автозагрузку классов
- отдельных функций/методов внутри php-файла, которые нигде больше не вызываются

чтобы можно было без подследствий удалить эти файлы и части кода?

Comment: Можете заюзать SonarQube. В Яндекс говорят что "маст хев". Сам не использовал, но говорят что штука крутая. [Ссылка на видео (Контроль качества кода в Яндекс)][1] https://www.sonarqube.org/
[1]: https://youtu.be/yu0gLSm_bTQ?t=714

Answer (score 1):

Полностью автоматических не встречал. Довольно не плохо эту задачу облегчают встроенные средства в PhpStorm (раздел рефакторинг), но не полностью, т.к. методы или классы могут хитро подгружаться (например из БД или конфига). В общем полюбому погружение в проект и наведение порядка ручками.